# Counting characters, words and lines in a string using a do-while loop | C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to convert a `while` loop that counts characters, words, and lines in a string, into a `do-while` loop.

Here is my `while` loop:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c;
    int characters = 0;
    int words = 1;
    int newlines = 0;
    printf("Input a string.  Press enter, then ctrl+Z, then enter once more to end string.\n");

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c>= 'A' && c<= 'Z')
            characters++;
        else if (c == ' ')
            words++;
        else if (c == '\n')
            newlines++;
    }

    printf("The number of characters is %d\n", characters);
    printf("The number of words is %d\n", words);
    printf("The number of newlines is %d\n", newlines);


    return 0;
}
```

I've been trying for hours to repeat the above process using a `do-while` loop, but to no avail.

Here is what I have so far:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;  

int main()
{
    int c;
    int characters = 0;
    int words = 0;
    int newlines = 0;
    printf("Input a string.  Press enter, then ctrl+Z, then enter once more to end string.\n");
    
    do 
    {
        c = getchar();
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            characters++;
        else if (c == ' ')
            words++;
        else if (c == '\n')
            newlines++;
    } while (c = getchar() != EOF);
        

    printf("The number of characters is %d\n", characters);
    printf("The number of words is %d\n", words);
    printf("The number of newlines is %d\n", newlines);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With the `do/while` you're skipping every other character. Count the `getchar` calls and the logic that follows each.

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: BTW with an empty string the word count would be 1. Additionally, in a string with multiple adjacent spaces the count will not be correct.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses.   I've learned a ton from this community but this was my very first post.  I'm glad I suck cause that just means I get to learn more from you all ;)

Comment: It's also good to know when you might suck. [It means you don't REALLY suck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main problems with the posted `do`-`while` loop.

The first one is that you are reading two characters but processing only character in each iteration of the loop.

The second one is that `while (c = getchar() != EOF)` does not do what you are hoping it would do. Due to operator precedence, that is equivalent to
`while (c = (getchar() != EOF))`.

```
do 
{
    c = getchar(); // OK the first time, not after that.
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        characters++;
    else if (c == ' ')
        words++;
    else if (c == '\n')
        newlines++;
} while (c = getchar() != EOF); // This is bad.
```

Even if you fix the second problem by using

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF);
```

it's stil not good because that line is good for detecting EOF but the character gets ignored for further processing.

---

You'll have to change the `do`-`while` loop to:

```
do 
{
    c = getchar();
    if ( c == EOF )
    {
        break;
    }

    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        characters++;
    else if (c == ' ')
        words++;
    else if (c == '\n')
        newlines++;
} while (true);
```

As you can see, it is not an improvement on the `while` loop. It is worse than the `while` loop from a cleanliness point of view.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the situation you have described is *far* better suited to using a normal `while` loop, rather than a `do ... while`. However, that fact notwithstanding, and without addressing other issues in your code (such as those mentioned in the comments), you can change many such loops simply by giving the 'control variable' an initial, 'dummy' value that has no effect inside the loop. In your case, a value of zero for `c` is hardly likely to ever be an *actual* input value, so you can use that:

```c
int c = 0; // Give c an initial (non)value.
do 
{
//  c = getchar(); // Remove this line, as it makes two 'reads' per loop!
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        characters++;
    else if (c == ' ')
        words++;
    else if (c == '\n')
        newlines++;
} while ((c = getchar()) != EOF); // Note the added parentheses!!!
```

But note, all this *really* achieves is adding one extra run through the loop, with no purpose.

Comment: Or you 'initialize' the `c` variable with a read: `int c = getchar();` ... but that adds an extra call to the code and, IMHO, makes it look dirtier.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

The thing you're attempting to do is completely antinatural and makes no sense. The situation you show should use a `while` loop and not just any loop.

**Solution:**

Technically you can still do this, but is **very bad style**:

```cpp
    do
    {
        bool do_end = (c = getchar()) != EOF;
        if(do_end)
            break;
        if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c>= 'A' && c<= 'Z'))
            characters++;
        else if (c == ' ')
            words++;
        else if (c == '\n')
            newlines++;
    } while (true);
```

The `while` loop is much better in this case, so don't use `do while` unless you actually need.

Additionally, consider that this solves the problem you asked for, but your code itself will have problem counting the amount of words if there are adjacent spaces or if the string is empty.

**Additional information:**

1. `using namespace std;` is considered a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and here you don't even need it because you're not using anything in the `std` namespace.
2. You are including `<string>` and `<typeinfo>` but not using any of the both.

Comment: Thank you, Gary.  Just through the process of implementing a do-while loop, I can tell it is far more inefficient than a while loop.  I'm new to C++ and trying to work through various flow controls and get a better understanding of how they work.  I am now trying to solve the  same problem using a switch function.  Thanks for the input on "using namespace std;".  The link you shared is helpful.